# joomla add custom table in administrator

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am quite new to Joomla.

On frontend I have created form that saves data into database. It works. Now I need to show data from DB in Joomla administrator. I do not have an idea how to do this.

So, I have to:
1) add new menu item SOMEHWERE in Joomla (where it should be, will it be component)?

2) I need to show Joomla like table with data from database in administrator

3) later I will also have to retrive data no ontl on administrator, but also on client view

How to do this in joomla? Please, give me some guides. I do not need exact sollution, just some guidelines. I can create all the code, but I do not know how to add it to Joomla properly.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective solution would be to create an administrator component. This will get you started [http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component)

Then you can follow this doc for making database queries from within Joomla. Regardless of what you come up with short of writing a component, you will need the 2nd link in order to make data base queries. standard mysql/php doesnt work correctly while inside Joomla.[http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aAccessing_the_database_using_JDatabase)

Comment: I have created com_refund in administrator/components/com_refund with refund.php file with text "Hello world administration". When I am testing it by administrator/index.php?option=com_helloworld (with or without index.php), it says Error loading component: com_refund, 1.

Comment: did you go to extensions manager and discover to find your new component, or did you install it through the install manager?

Comment: No, I just followed instructions in document and it doesn't says I have to install before testing

Comment: ok well you will definitively have to install it either through the extension manager either by "install" or "discovery".

Comment: And by that Sandra means navigate to Extensions > Extension Manager > Discover and then click Purge Cache and then Discover. After that you should see your custom component listed. Check the box and click install. That creates the component entry in the Joomla database, and you won't have that problem anymore. It also creates the Menu Item under the Components Menu.